# If else acts extremely weird and broken

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Edit I defined ANIM_MEDITATON = "Meditation" but it sees ANIM_MEDITATION as "Strike" I don't know why.

SO I'm changing my question. Even though I defined

```
[HideInInspector] public string ANIM_MEDITATION = "Meditation";
```

When I Log ANIM_MEDITATION in Awake, it logs "Strike"

I've created an if else block that acts weird.

When I write it like this, actually there is more if else conditions but main logic is like this, it does not enter to the 3rd if

```
 public void UpdateAnimationTimes()
    {
        AnimationClip[] clips = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
    
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            if (clip.name == "Ledge Climb")
            {
                animLedgeClimbTime = clip.length;
            } 
            else if (clip.name == "Meditation")
            {
                animMeditationTime = clip.length;
            }
            // DOES NOT ENTER HERE?!
            else if (clip.name == "Strike" )
            {
                animStrikeTime = clip.length;
            } 
            else if (clip.name == "Strike 2")
            {
                animStrike2Time = clip.length;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it works like this! Only thing I did is change the if order

```
 public void UpdateAnimationTimes()
    {
        AnimationClip[] clips = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
    
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
/// ENTERS HERE!!!!
            if (clip.name == "Strike")
            {
                animStrikeTime = clip.length;
            } else if (clip.name == ANIM_LEDGE_CLIMB)
            {
                animLedgeClimbTime= clip.length;
            } 
            else if (clip.name == "Meditation")
            {
                animMeditationTime = clip.length;
            }
            else if (clip.name == "Strike 2")
            {
                animStrike2Time = clip.length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `ANIM_STRIKE`? Does it have the same value as `ANIM_LEDGE_CLIMB` or `ANIM_MEDITATION`?

Comment: what are the actual values of your constants? also: this is basically an `if`-verison of the [loop-switch-antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036330/how-to-avoid-a-loop-switch-anti-pattern) - you should probably refactor this.

Comment: plus: i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). your question is missing some information to reproduce the problem, so we can only guess.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann is it? If I understand correctly the `loop-switch-antipattern` is more like a state machine where you are supposed to execute a sequence of actions within the loop while the switch parameter is changed within the switch ... that's not really the case here

Comment: @derHugo under the assumption that `clips` contains one entry for each defined clipname, it kinda is, IMHO. but either way, refactoring it to a mapping instead of a loop where each entry has to be coded manually would be beneficial.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann totally agree with the last part ... using a `Dictionary<AnimationClip, float>` would completely solve the issue without going by strings at all in the first place ^^

Comment: ANIM_STRIKE = "Strike", ANIM_LEDGE_CLIMB = "Ledge Climb". Names are correct, even trying with == "Strike" is not working

Comment: Sounds like something sets ANIM_MEDITATION somewhere else. There's no way we can help you without more code.

Comment: And your edit confuses me. If you changed out the constants to strings and you still get this issue, your new question shouldn't matter. Are you sure the new if statements cause the same issues? You forgot to change ANIM_LEDGE_CLIMB in the second example btw

Comment: It's probably being serialized and hidden - use `[NonSerializable]` Instead of `[HideInInspector]`. Anyway, question needs a [mre] to remain open.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use the switch case statement and place a brackpoint on each case to see clearly :

```
        switch (clip.name)
        {
            case ANIM_STRIKE:
                animStrikeTime = clip.length;
                break;
            case ANIM_LEDGE_CLIMB:
                animLedgeClimbTime = clip.length;
                break;
            case ANIM_MEDITATION:
                animMeditationTime = clip.length;
                break;
            case ANIM_STRIKE_2:
                animStrike2Time = clip.length;
                break;
            default:
                //default
                break;
        }
```